# Deploy multiple webapp projects (different areas) to same site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, razorengine

Multiple Asp.Net Framework 4.6.2 MVC/Razor projects within a single solution.
They use Areas, and each project will implement one or more Areas, distinct from the other.
One project acts as the "primary", and includes the global.asax.
The "subordinate" apps can know about the "primary", but not vice versa.

**Is it possible to deploy these to the same web site?** (on-prem VM).
There would be some collisions, such as the _Layout.cshtml.

Some how I'd have to be able to setup dependency injections for the classes in the "subordinate" project assembly.

Thanks

-John

Comment: maybe using a manual process you could, but it could end up being tricky because in an MVC site much of it gets pre-compiled into DLLs. Why did you do them as separate projects in the first place? Is it strictly necessary to do that?

Comment: This is a client of mine. They hoped to create an extensible framework, where the main web site could manage facilities like authentication and other services. While Area writers just worried about the business app. They have different groups developing, so there is no opportunity to build together. They're ok with customizing the deployment, and the binaries they just drop into the site's Bin folder. The subordinate app has no global.asax, and just configures dependency injection through the Area registration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible easily, because so much of an MVC site is pre-compiled into DLLs, and yet some of it (e.g. view files) must be actually physically deployed outside the DLL. You are likely to run into conflicts or confusion I think. It's certainly not a reliable, definable process that you could count on in production.

Here are some alternative suggestions to solve the underlying problem, based on what you described in the comments. These are just ideas, some of which I've done or seen done, and might not suit you, but any of them should be a lot easier to manage than trying to bodge the deployment process:

1) Try building the areas in separate projects as you do now, but without all the generic MVC stuff that surrounds it. I.e. Do it as if they were libraries only containing the files specific to their functionality. Then you can package them up as Nuget packages. When they're ready, install the packages into the "main" site to create the combined solution. That way you won't run into conflicts of layout pages etc. If one of the sub-projects changes, then the main site can just upgrade the NuGet package. You can create private NuGet feeds either via Visual Studio Online (if you have a subscription) or on the simplest level via a shared network folder. I think other online vendors offer private feeds as well. We've done that quite successfully to apply some default styles, scripts, layouts etc to all our various MVC apps.

2) Re-architect your solution as a series of separate apps (that's the bit you've already got), but with a central service that provides federated authentication/authorisation (e.g. ADFS, IdentityServer or similar), and a web API (or APIs) that the other sites can call to access other centralised services and functions programatically. I'm pretty confident you can use routing config and shared sessions to make it all hang together as if it was actually one site.

3) Build it all out as just one site, but with clear separation for the various teams about the back-end services, classes etc that they are responsible for, so they don't interfere with each other's code. Each team can check-in code to different branches in source control and only merge to the shared branches for integration/system testing and deployment. You can use a continuous integration server to test the build process after each check-in, and if you have robust code review and gated check-ins you can stop people changing stuff that they shouldn't. You also have the flexibility to release with/without updates from the various areas, if the development lifecycles are going at different speeds.

4) Some combination of all of the above!